# Can I make `cut` change a file in place?

Tags: shell, files, io-redirection, cut

The [`man` page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cut) doesn't give me much hope, but I'm hoping it's an undocumented (and/or GNU-specific) feature.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't. Either use ed or GNU sed or perl, or do what they do behind the scenes, which is to create a new file for the contents.

`ed`, portable:

```
ed foo <<EOF
1,$s/^\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\).*/\1,\3/
w
q
EOF
```

GNU `sed`:

```
sed -i -e 's/^\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\).*/\1,\3/' foo
```

Perl:

```
perl -i -l -F, -pae 'print @F[1,3]' foo
```

`cut`, creating a new file (recommended, because if your script is interrupted, you can just run it again):

```
cut -d , -f 1,3 <foo >foo.new &&
mv -f foo.new foo
```

`cut`, replacing the file in place (retains the ownership and permissions of `foo`, but needs protection against interruptions):

```
cp -f foo foo.old &&
cut -d , -f 1,3 <foo.old >foo &&
rm foo.old
```

I recommend using one of the `cut`-based methods. That way you don't depend on any non-standard tool, you can use the best tool for the job, and you control the behavior on interrupt.

Comment: Better than `.old` method for in-place changes, `echo "$(cut -d , -f 1,3 <foo)" > foo`

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut No, this is not “better”. It's more fragile. Its only benefit is that it's shorter to type. The main problem with your method is that if an error happens while processing the input file or writing the output, the data is lost. It also doesn't work with binary data: the output will be truncated at the first null byte. Even with text files, it removes empty lines from the end of the file. With large files, it may fail because the data has to be stored as a string in the shell's memory (and remember, if this happens, the data is lost).

Comment: o.O Thanks, I didn't know there might be problems with null byte

Comment: I think this is simpler:
`cut -d , -f 1,3 foo > foo.new`
`rm foo` 
`mv foo.new foo`

Comment: @LoMaPh Indeed, I don't know why I renamed the old file: it doesn't have any advantages over renaming the new file. It's also simpler because you don't need the step `rm foo`. And you shouldn't call `rm foo`, because `mv foo.new foo` is atomic: it removes the old version and puts the new version in place at the same time.

Comment: What about `cp -f foo foo.new && cut -d , -f 1,3 <foo >foo.new && mv -f foo.new foo` to retain perms/ownership AND protect against interruptions?

Comment: @stackprotector That works too, provided that the file isn't so large that you'd mind temporarily duplicating the data.

Comment: In that case, one could then use `cut -d , -f 1,3 <foo >foo.new && chmod --reference foo foo.new && chown --reference foo foo.new && mv -f foo.new foo` to retain perms/ownership and protect against interruptions. Thx for clarification!

Answer (score 31):

The [moreutils](http://joey.kitenet.net/code/moreutils/) package from ubuntu (and also [debian](http://packages.debian.org/source/unstable/moreutils)) has a program called `sponge`, which sort-of also solves your problem.

From man sponge:

> sponge  reads  standard  input and
>   writes it out to the specified file.
>   Unlike a shell redirect, sponge soaks
>   up all its input  before  opening the 
>   output file. This allows constricting
>   pipelines that read from and write to
>   the same file.

Which would let you do something like:

```
cut -d <delim> -f <fields> somefile | sponge somefile
```

Answer (score 9):

I don't think that is possible using `cut` alone.  I couldn't find it in the man or info page. You can do something such as

```
mytemp=$(mktemp) && cut -d" " -f1 file > $mytemp && mv $mytemp file
```

`mktemp` makes you a relatively safe temporary file that you can pipe the `cut` output into.

Answer (score 1):

Try vim-way:

```
$ ex -s +'%!cut -c 1-10' -cxa file.txt
```

This will edit the file in-place (so do the backup first).

Alternatively use [`grep`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3979548/55075), [`sed`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7573368/55075) or [`gawk`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16529716/55075).

Answer (score 0):

You can use slurp with POSIX Awk:

```
cut -b1 file | awk 'BEGIN{RS="";getline<"-";print>ARGV[1]}' file
```

[Example](//github.com/svnpenn/stdlib/blob/1896e06/stdlib.sh#L15-L23)

Answer (score 0):

Well, since `cut` produces less output than it reads, you can do:

```
cut -c1 < file 1<> file
```

That is, make its stdin the `file` open in read-only mode and its stdout the `file` open in read+write mode without truncation (`<>`).

That way, `cut` will just overwrite the file over itself. However, it will leave the rest of the file untouched. For instance, if `file` contains:

```
foo
bar
```

The output will become:

```
f
b
bar
```

The `f\nb\n` have replaced `foo\n`, but `bar` is still there. You'd need to truncate the file after `cut` has finished.

With `ksh93`, you can do it with its `<>;` operator which acts like `<>` except that if the command succeeds, `ftruncate()` is called on the file descriptor. So:

```
cut -c1 < file 1<>; file
```

With other shells, you'd need to do the `ftruncate()` via some other means like:

```
{ cut -c1 < file; perl -e 'truncate STDOUT, tell STDOUT';} 1<> file
```

though invoking `perl` just for that is a bit overkill here especially considering that `perl` can easily do that `cut`'s job like:

```
perl -pi -e '$_ = substr($_, 0, 1)' file
```

Beware that with all methods that involve actual in-place rewriting, if the operation is interrupted midway, you'll end up with a corrupted file. Using a temporary second file avoids this problem.