# Is there a way to modify a file in-place?

Tags: text-processing, grep, large-files

I have a fairly large file (35Gb), and I would like to filter this file in situ (i.e. I don't have enough disk space for another file), specifically I want to grep and ignore some patterns — is there a way to do this without using another file?

Let's say I want to filter out all the lines containing `foo:` for example...

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want the output to go to stdout?

Comment: @Tshepang: I think he wants to write back to the same file.

Comment: @Faheem, that is correct.

Comment: "in situ" is a Latin phrase meaning "in place". Literally, "in position".

Comment: In that case, the question should be clearer, something like *is there a way to modify a file in-place*?

Comment: The only things you can do with a file is to overwrite some bytes in place (i.e. overwrite byte position X with a new byte value), append to it (i.e. write after the existing bytes) and to truncate it (i.e. remove everything after position Y). You can't insert or remove bytes in the middle. So you'll need a specialized tool for your particular task, that moves data around as it finds chunks to delete.

Comment: @Tshepang, "in situ" is a fairly common phrase used in English to describe exactly that - I thought the title was fairly self explanatory... @Gilles, I figured as much, easier to wait for more disk space! ;)

Comment: That's if you dont mind screwing the file with your edit.  Otherwise you'd better take a backup.  And if you have a backup, you don't need to do it in-place...  If you're short on disk space, you may try making a compressed backup.

Comment: I don't have a solution, but I [this blog posting](http://backreference.org/2011/01/29/in-place-editing-of-files/) talks about the in-place editing function of things like perl and sed and how they actually create a temp file. 

More importantly, it talks about all the things NOT to do and why not to do them, going in to great technical depth.

Comment: @Nim: Well, I think *in-place* is more common than *in situ*.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089877/best-way-to-modify-a-file-when-using-pipes

Comment: In practice, **that is a scenario justifying some other approach**, like have a *directory* containing *several* smaller files, or some database (perhaps [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/)...) or some indexed file (like [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/))

Comment: "Filter out all the lines containing `foo:`" is unclear. It could mean "extract all lines containing `foo:`", but it could also mean "remove all lines containing `foo:`".

Comment: Not sure it works for your disk and memory constraints but https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5846/2995 suggests to pipe the output to `sponge`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

At the system call level this should be possible. A program can open your target file for writing without truncating it and start writing what it reads from stdin. When reading EOF, the output file can be truncated.

Since you are filtering lines from the input, the output file write position should always be less than the read position. This means you should not corrupt your input with the new output.

However, finding a program that does this is the problem. `dd(1)` has the option `conv=notrunc` that does not truncate the output file on open, but it also does not truncate at the end, leaving the original file contents after the grep contents (with a command like `grep pattern bigfile | dd of=bigfile conv=notrunc`)

Since it is very simple from a system call perspective, I wrote a small program and tested it on a small (1MiB) full loopback filesystem. It did what you wanted, but you really want to test this with some other files first. It's always going to be risky overwriting a file.

**overwrite.c**

```
/* This code is placed in the public domain by camh */

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int outfd;
        char buf[1024];
        int nread;
        off_t file_length;

        if (argc != 2) {
                fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <output_file>\n", argv[0]);
                exit(1);
        }
        if ((outfd = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY)) == -1) {
                perror("Could not open output file");
                exit(2);
        }
        while ((nread = read(0, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0) {
                if (write(outfd, buf, nread) == -1) {
                        perror("Could not write to output file");
                        exit(4);
                }
        }
        if (nread == -1) {
                perror("Could not read from stdin");
                exit(3);
        }
        if ((file_length = lseek(outfd, 0, SEEK_CUR)) == (off_t)-1) {
                perror("Could not get file position");
                exit(5);
        }
        if (ftruncate(outfd, file_length) == -1) {
                perror("Could not truncate file");
                exit(6);
        }
        close(outfd);
        exit(0);
}
```

You would use it as:

```
grep pattern bigfile | overwrite bigfile
```

I'm mostly posting this for others to comment on before you try it. Perhaps someone else knows of a program that does something similar that is more tested.

Comment: I wanted to see if I could get away without writing something for it! :) I guess this will do the trick! Thanks!

Comment: +1 for C; does seem to work, but I see a potential problem: the file is being read from the left side at the time as the right is writing to the same file and unless you coordinate the two processes, you would have overwrite problems potentially on the same blocks.  It might be better for the file integrity to use smaller block size since most of the core tools will likely use 8192.  This might slow down the program enough to avoid conflicts (but cannot guarantee). Maybe read larger portions into memory (not all) and write in smaller blocks.  Could also add a nanosleep(2)/usleep(3).

Comment: @Arcege: Writing is not done in blocks. If your read process has read 2 bytes and your write process writes 1 byte, only the first byte will change and the read process can continue reading at byte 3 with the original contents at that point unchanged. Since `grep` will not output more data than it reads, the write position should always be behind the read position. Even if you are writing at the same rate as reading, it will still be ok. Try rot13 with this instead of grep, and then again. md5sum the before and after and you'll see its the same.

Comment: Nice. This may be a valuable addition to Joey Hess's [moreutils](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/moreutils/). You [can use `dd`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11067/is-there-a-way-to-filter-a-file-in-place/11114#11114), but it's cumbersome.

Comment: 'grep pattern bigfile | overwrite bigfile' - I got this working without errors, but what I don't understand is - isn't the requirement to replace what's in the pattern with some other text? so shouldn't it be something like: 'grep pattern bigfile | overwrite /replace-text/ bigfile'

Comment: I am getting stderr "file truncated" => I thought the whole point of this was to avoid truncating files?

Comment: @AlexanderMills There is no "replacement" in the requirements, just filtering. i.e. select lines that match a pattern and overwrite the source file with lines matching the pattern from the same file. Not sure about your "file truncated" error. The program does not output that text (unless you've truncated the error message), so it's not the overwrite program outputting that.

Answer (score 30):

With any Bourne-like shell:

```
{
  cat < bigfile | grep -v to-exclude
  perl -e 'truncate STDOUT, tell STDOUT'
} 1<> bigfile
```

For some reason, it seems people tend to forget about that 40 year old¹ and [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_07) read+write redirection operator.

We open `bigfile` in read+write mode and (what matters most here) without truncation on `stdout` while `bigfile` is open (separately) on `cat`'s `stdin`. After `grep` has terminated, and if it has removed some lines, `stdout` now points somewhere within `bigfile`, we need to get rid of what's beyond this point. Hence the `perl` command that truncates the file (`truncate STDOUT`) at the current position (as returned by `tell STDOUT`).

(the `cat` is for GNU `grep` that otherwise complains if stdin and stdout point to the same file).

---

<sup>¹ Well, while `<>` has been in the Bourne shell from the start in the late seventies, it was initially [undocumented and not properly implemented](https://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/bourne/). It was not in the original implementation of `ash` from 1989 and, while it is a POSIX `sh` redirection operator (since the early 90s as POSIX `sh` is based on `ksh88` which always had it), it was not added to FreeBSD `sh` for instance until 2000, so portably *15 year old* is probably more accurate. Also note that the default file descriptor when not specified is 0 in all shells, except that in `ksh93` it changed from 0 to 1 in ksh93t+ in 2010 (breaking backward compatibility  and POSIX compliance)</sup>

Comment: Can you explain the `perl -e 'truncate STDOUT, tell STDOUT'`? It works for me without including that. Any way to achieve the same thing without using Perl?

Comment: @AaronBlenkush, see edit.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant - thank you. I was there then, but don't remember this....
A reference for the "36 year old" standard would be fun, since it isn't mentioned at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell.
And what was it used for? I see a reference to a bug fix in SunOS 5.6: `redirection "<>" fixed and documented (used in /etc/inittab f.i.). ` which is one hint.

Comment: @nealmcb, see edit.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas How does your solution compares to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/557566/167041)? It apparently does the same thing but looks simpler.

Comment: @akhan, that [other approach](//serverfault.com/a/557566) replaces the file with a new one, it doesn't overwrite the same file in place. In particular, permissions ownership, and other metadata of the original file will be lost.

Comment: Amazing, @StéphaneChazelas (as always). Can we do `cat <&1` instead of `cat < bigfile`?

Comment: @AndréChalella, no we need to open the file a second time so we get two separate *open file descriptions* that have independant *cursors* within the file.

Answer (score 21):

You can use `sed` to edit files in place (but this does create an intermediate temporary file):

To remove all lines containing `foo`:

```
sed -i '/foo/d' myfile
```

To keep all lines containing `foo`:

```
sed -i '/foo/!d' myfile
```

Comment: interesting, will this temp file need to be the same size as the original though?

Comment: Yes, so that's probably no good.

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking for since it creates a second file.

Comment: This solution will fail on a read-only file system, where "read-only" means that your `$HOME` *will* be writable, but `/tmp` will be __read-only__ (by default). For instance, if you have Ubuntu and you've booted into the Recovery Console, this is commonly the case. Also, the here-document operator `<<<` will not work there either, as it requires `/tmp` to be __r/w__ because it will write a temporary file into there as well. (cf. [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98606/bash-some-issue-when-using-read-variable-on-a-read-only-root-partition-a) incl. a `strace`'d output)

Comment: yeah this won't work for me either, all the sed commands I have tried will replace the current file with a new a file (despite the --in-place flag).

Comment: For the sed I'm using (MacOSX) the above syntax is wrong; -i takes an extension for the backup copy; this works: sed -e '/foo/d' -i .bak myfile

Comment: @syntaxerror seems to have retired from [SE]; last seen over a year ago. Can anybody verify or support (or refute) his/her claim (that sometimes `/tmp` is read-only, while other filesystems are read/write)? It seems to me that `/tmp` should always be writable (except when it’s full, I suppose), and any system that makes it read-only is a broken system.

Answer (score 21):

I'll assume that your filter command is what I'll call a *prefix shrinking filter*, which has the property that byte N in the output is never written before having read at least N bytes of input. `grep` has this property (as long as it's only filtering and not doing other things like adding line numbers for matches). With such a filter, you can overwrite the input as you go along. Of course, you need to be sure of not making any mistake, since the overwritten part at the beginning of the file will be lost forever.

Most unix tools only give a choice of appending to a file or truncating it, with no possibility of overwriting it. The one exception in the standard toolbox is [`dd`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29), which can be told not to truncate its output file. So the plan is to filter the command into `dd conv=notrunc`. This doesn't change the size of the file, so we also grab the length of the new content and truncate the file to that length (again with `dd`). Note that this task is inherently non-robust — if an error occurs, you're on your own.

```
export LC_ALL=C
n=$({ grep -v foo <big_file |
      tee /dev/fd/3 |
      dd of=big_file conv=notrunc; } 3>&1 | wc -c)
dd if=/dev/null of=big_file bs=1 seek=$n
```

You can write rougly equivalent Perl. Here's a quick implementation that doesn't try to be efficient. Of course, you may want to do your initial filtering directly in that language as well.

```
grep -v foo <big_file | perl -e '
  close STDOUT;
  open STDOUT, "+<", $ARGV[0] or die;
  while (<STDIN>) {print}
  truncate STDOUT, tell STDOUT or die
' big_file
```

Answer (score 10):

Even though this is an old question, it seems to me it's a perennial question, and a more general, clearer solution is available than has been suggested so far.  Credit where credit is due: I'm not sure I would have come up with it without considering Stéphane Chazelas's mention of the `<>` update operator.

Opening a file *for update* in a Bourne shell is of limited utility.  The shell gives you no way to seek on a file, and no way to set its new length (if shorter than the old one).  But that's easily remedied, so easily I'm surprised it's not among the standard utilities in `/usr/bin`.

This works:

```
$ grep -n foo T
8:foo
$ (exec 4<>T; grep foo T >&4 && ftruncate 4) && nl T; 
     1  foo
```

As does this (hat tip to Stéphane):

```
$ { grep foo T && ftruncate; } 1<>T  && nl T; 
     1  foo
```

(I'm using GNU grep.  Perhaps something's changed since he wrote his answer.)

Except, you have no **/usr/bin/ftruncate**.  For a couple dozen lines of C, you can, see below.  This **ftruncate** utility truncates an arbitrary file descriptor to an arbitrary length, defaulting to standard output and the current position.

The above command (1st example)

- opens file descriptor 4 on `T` for update.  Just as with open(2), opening the file this way positions the current offset at 0.
- **grep** then processes `T` normally, and the shell redirects its output to `T` via descriptor 4.
- **ftruncate** calls ftruncate(2) on descriptor 4, setting the length to the value of the current offset (exactly where **grep** left it).

The subshell then exits, closing descriptor 4.  Here is **ftruncate**:

```
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  off_t i, fd=1, len=0;
  off_t *addrs[2] = { &fd, &len };

  for( i=0; i < argc-1; i++ ) {
    if( sscanf(argv[i+1], "%lu", addrs[i]) < 1 ) {
      err(EXIT_FAILURE, "could not parse %s as number", argv[i+1]);
    }
  }

  if( argc < 3 && (len = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR)) == -1 ) {
    err(EXIT_FAILURE, "could not ftell fd %d as number", (int)fd);
  }


  if( 0 != ftruncate((int)fd, len) ) {
    err(EXIT_FAILURE, argc > 1? argv[1] : "stdout");
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

N.B., ftruncate(2) is nonportable when used in this way.  For absolute generality, read the last written byte, reopen the file O_WRONLY, seek, write the byte, and close.

Given that the question is 5 years old, I'm going to say this solution is nonobvious.  It takes advantage of **exec** to open a new descriptor, and the `<>` operator, both of which are arcane.  I can't think of a standard utility that manipulates an inode by file descriptor.  (The syntax could be `ftruncate >&4`, but I'm not sure that an improvement.)  It's considerably shorter than camh's competent, exploratory answer.  It's just a little clearer than Stéphane's, IMO, unless you like Perl more than I do.  I hope someone finds it useful.

A different way to do the same thing would be an executable version of lseek(2) that reports the current offset; the output could be used for **/usr/bin/truncate**, which some Linuxi provide.

Answer (score 5):

[`ed`](http://bama.ua.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?ed) is probably the right choice to edit a file in-place:

```
ed my_big_file << END_OF_ED_COMMANDS
g/foo:/d
w
q 
END_OF_ED_COMMANDS
```

Comment: I like the idea, but unless different `ed` versions behave differently..... this is from `man ed` (GNU Ed 1.4)... `If  invoked  with a file argument, then a copy of file is read into the editor's buffer.  Changes are made to  this  copy  and  not  directly  to  file itself.`

Comment: @fred, if you're implying that saving the changes will not affect the named file, you're incorrect. I interpret that quote to say that your changes aren't reflected *until* you save them. I do concede that `ed` isn't a gool solution for editing 35GB files since the file is read into a buffer.

Comment: I was thinking that it meant the *full* file would be loaded into the buffer.. but perhaps only the section(s) it neeeds are loaded into the buffer.. I've been curious about ed for a while... I thought it *could* do in-situ editing... I'll just have to try a *big* file... If it works it is a reasonable solution, but as I write, I'm starting to think that this may be what inspired *sed* (freed from working with large data chunks...  I've noticed that 'ed' can actually accept streamed input from a script (prefixed with `!` ), so it may have a few more interesting tricks up its sleeve.

Comment: I am pretty sure the write operation in `ed` truncates the file and rewrites it. So this won't alter the data on disk in-place as the OP desires. Also, it can't work if the file is too big to be loaded in memory.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a bash read/write file descriptor to open your file (to overwrite it in-situ), then `sed` and `truncate` ... but of course, don't ever allow your changes to be larger than the amount of data read so far.

Here is the script (uses: bash variable $BASHPID )

```
# Create a test file
  echo "going abc"  >junk
  echo "going def" >>junk
  echo "# ORIGINAL file";cat junk |tee >( wc=($(wc)); echo "# ${wc[0]} lines, ${wc[2]} bytes" ;echo )
#
# Assign file to fd 3, and open it r/w
  exec 3<> junk  
#
# Choose a unique filename to hold the new file size  and the pid 
# of the semi-asynchrounous process to which 'tee' streams the new file..  
  [[ ! -d "/tmp/$USER" ]] && mkdir "/tmp/$USER" 
  f_pid_size="/tmp/$USER/pid_size.$(date '+%N')" # %N is a GNU extension: nanoseconds
  [[ -f "$f_pid_size" ]] && { echo "ERROR: Work file already exists: '$f_pid_size'" ;exit 1 ; }
#
# run 'sed' output to 'tee' ... 
#  to modify the file in-situ, and to count the bytes  
  <junk sed -e "s/going //" |tee >(echo -n "$BASHPID " >"$f_pid_size" ;wc -c >>"$f_pid_size") >&3
#
#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
# The byte-counting process is not a child-process, 
# so 'wait' doesn't work... but wait we must...  
  pid_size=($(cat "$f_pid_size")) ;pid=${pid_size[0]}  
  # $f_pid_size may initially contain only the pid... 
  # get the size when pid termination is assured
  while [[ "$pid" != "" ]] ; do
    if ! kill -0 "$pid" 2>/dev/null; then
       pid=""  # pid has terminated. get the byte count
       pid_size=($(cat "$f_pid_size")) ;size=${pid_size[1]}
    fi
  done
  rm "$f_pid_size"
#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
#
  exec 3>&- # close fd 3.
  newsize=$(cat newsize)
  echo "# MODIFIED file (before truncating)";cat junk |tee >( wc=($(wc)); echo "# ${wc[0]} lines, ${wc[2]} bytes" ;echo )  cat junk
#
 truncate -s $newsize junk
 echo "# NEW (truncated) file";cat junk |tee >( wc=($(wc)); echo "# ${wc[0]} lines, ${wc[2]} bytes" ;echo )  cat junk
#
exit
```

Here is the test output

```
# ORIGINAL file
going abc
going def
# 2 lines, 20 bytes

# MODIFIED file (before truncating)
abc
def
c
going def
# 4 lines, 20 bytes

# NEW (truncated) file
abc
def
# 2 lines, 8 bytes
```

Answer (score 5):

For the benefit of anyone googling the question "how do I modify a file in-place?", the correct answer **in the usual case** is *stop* looking for obscure shell features that risk corrupting your file for negligible performance gain, and instead use some variation of this pattern:

```
grep "foo" file > file.new && mv file.new file
```

Only in the *extremely uncommon situation* that this is for some reason not feasible, should you seriously consider any of the other answers on this page (although they are certainly interesting to read). I will concede that the OP's conundrum of having no disk space to create a second file is exactly such a situation. Although even then, there are other options available, e.g. as provided by @Ed Randall and @Basile Starynkevitch.

Comment: I may missunderstand but has nothing to do with what the OP originaly asked. aka inline edit of bigfile without having enough diskspace for temporary file.

Comment: @Kiwy It is an answer aimed at other viewers of this question (of which there have been almost 15,000 so far). The question "Is there a way to modify a file in-place?" has broader relevance than the OP's specific use case.

Comment: Not having space for a huge (35 GB) temp is what makes OP's Q interesting. This scenario may be inconvenient, however it's not unreasonable   The Q does not involve a "negligible performance gain", it concern a resource limitation.  OP is not asking for an "obscure shell feature", just for a solution.

Comment: @ShpielMeister I've just edited my answer to hopefully clarify that I am providing this answer for the benefit of anyone who comes to this page looking for an answer to the *simple* version of the question "how do I modify a file in-place?". I know the OP's question is not that simple. I just want to help other readers. But if you still think the answer is unhelpful, please feel free to down-vote it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd memory-map the file, do everything in-place using char* pointers to naked memory, then unmap the file and truncate it.

Comment: +1, but only because the widespread availability of 64-bit CPUs and OSes makes it possible to do that with a 35 GB file now. Those still on 32-bit systems (the vast majority even of this site's audience, I suspect) won't be able to use this solution.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly *in-situ* but - this could be of use in similar circumstances.
If disk space is a problem, compress the file first (since it is text this will give a huge reduction) then use sed (or grep, or whatever) in the usual way in the middle of an uncompress/compress pipeline.

```
# Reduce size from ~35Gb to ~6Gb
$ gzip MyFile

# Edit file, creating another ~6Gb file
$ gzip -dc <MyFile.gz | sed -e '/foo/d' | gzip -c >MyEditedFile.gz
```

Comment: But surely gzip is writing the compressed version to the disk before replacing it with the compressed version, so you need at least that much extra space, unlike the other options. But it is safer, if you've got the space (which I don't....)

Comment: This is a clever solution that can be further optimized to perform only one compression instead of two: `sed -e '/foo/d' MyFile | gzip -c >MyEditedFile.gz && gzip -dc MyEditedFile.gz >MyFile`

Answer (score 0):

**Use VIM**

It is possible to pass VIM a list of commands or a script to execute in addition to what files to open.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235112/how-to-run-a-series-of-vim-commands-from-command-prompt for a big list of methods, but the very simplest is that `vim -S <scriptfilename> <filename>` will execute `scriptfilename` as a list of commands after loading `filename` into the buffer.

This will still have a temporary file, but since you're just removing particular lines it will be tiny.  It will also be slower than grep, but it does give you the ability to do more complex alterations as well.

Don't forget to put a "w" command at the end of your script to save the changes.