# How to obtain inverse behavior for `tail` and `head`?

Tags: text-processing, tail, head

Is there a way to `head`/`tail` a document and get the reverse output; because you don't know how many lines there are in a document?

I.e. I just want to get everything but the first 2 lines of `foo.txt` to append to another document.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use this to strip the *first* two lines:

```
tail -n +3 foo.txt
```

and this to strip the *last* two lines, if your implementation of `head` supports it:

```
head -n -2 foo.txt
```

(assuming the file ends with `\n` for the latter)

---

Just like for the standard usage of `tail` and `head` these operations are not destructive. Use `>out.txt` if you want to redirect the output to some new file:

```
tail -n +3 foo.txt >out.txt
```

In the case `out.txt` already exists, it will overwrite this file. Use `>>out.txt` instead of `>out.txt` if you'd rather have the output appended to `out.txt`.

Comment: re *"head, when file ends with `\n`"*.. It works for all negative integers other than `-n -0` which returns *nothing at all*, just as `-n 0` would (using: head (GNU coreutils) 7.4) ... However when a trailing `\n` is present, `-n -0` does print as might be expected from the `-`, ie. it prints the entire file... So it does work for all non-zero negative values.. but `-0` fails when there is no trailing `\n`

Comment: @fred: Strange indeed… (same with 8.12 here).

Comment: Is this operation destructive? As i want it to copy the inverse of the first two lines of the document to another?

Comment: @Chris: No, they just print the result on their "standard output", which is usually connected to the terminal. I've added some details on how to redirect the output to some files.

Comment: `head -n -2` is not [POSIX compatible](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/head.html).

Comment: `head -n -2 foo.txt` says `head: illegal line count -- -2`

Answer (score 13):

If you want all but the first N-1 lines, call `tail` with the number of lines `+N`. (The number is the number of the first line you want to retain, starting at 1, i.e. +1 means start at the top, +2 means skip one line and so on).

```
tail -n +3 foo.txt >>other-document
```

There's no easy, portable way to skip the last N lines. GNU `head` allows `head -n +N` as a counterpart of `tail -n +N`. Otherwise, if you have `tac` (e.g. GNU or Busybox), you can combine it with tail:

```
tac | tail -n +3 | tac
```

Portably, you can use an awk filter (untested):

```
awk -vskip=2 '{
    lines[NR] = $0;
    if (NR > skip) print lines[NR-skip];
    delete lines[NR-skip];
}'
```

If you want to remove the last few lines from a large file, you can determine the byte offset of the piece to truncate then perform the truncation with `dd`.

```
total=$(wc -c < /file/to/truncate)
chop=$(tail -n 42 /file/to/truncate | wc -c)
dd if=/dev/null of=/file/to/truncate seek=1 bs="$((total-chop))"
```

You can't truncate a file in place at the beginning, though if you need to remove the first few lines of a huge file, you can [move the contents around](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11067/885).

Comment: On some systems (like modern Linux), you can truncate (collapse) a file in place at the beginning, but usually only by an amount that is multiple of the FS block size (so not really useful in this case).

Answer (score 4):

To remove the first n lines GNU sed can be used. For example if n = 2

```
sed -n '1,2!p' input-file
```

The `!` mean "exclude this interval". As you can imagine, more complicated result can be obtained, for example

```
sed -n '3,5p;7p'
```

that will show line 3,4,5,7. More power come from use of regular expressions instead of addresses.

The limitation is that the lines numbers must be known in advance.

Comment: Why not just `sed 1,2d`?  Simpler is usually better.  Also, nothing in your examples is specific to GNU Sed; your commands all use standard [POSIX features of Sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html).

Answer (score 3):

From the `tail` man page (GNU `tail`, that is):

```
-n, --lines=K
   output the last K lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n +K to
   output lines starting with the Kth
```

Thus, the following should append all but the first 2 lines of `somefile.txt` to `anotherfile.txt`:

```
tail --lines=+3 somefile.txt >> anotherfile.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

```sh
{   head -n2 >/dev/null
    cat  >> other_document
}   <infile
```

If *`<infile`* is a regular, *`lseek()`*-able file, then yes, by all means, feel free. The above is a fully POSIXly supported construct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `diff` to compare the output of `head`/`tail` to the original file and then remove what is the same, therefore getting the inverse.

```
diff --unchanged-group-format='' foo.txt <(head -2 foo.txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

While `tail -n +4` to output the file starting at the 4th line (all but the first 3 lines) is standard and portable, its `head` counterpart (`head -n -3`, all but the last 3 lines) is not.

Portably, you'd do:

```
sed '$d' | sed '$d' | sed '$d'
```

Or:

```
sed -ne :1 -e '1,3{N;b1' -e '}' -e 'P;N;D'
```

(beware that on some systems where `sed` has a pattern space of limited size, that doesn't scale to large values of `n`).

Or:

```
awk 'NR>3 {print l[NR%3]}; {l[NR%3]=$0}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I clearly understood your need.

You've several ways to complete your request :

```
tail -n$(expr $(cat /etc/passwd|wc -l) - 2) /etc/passwd
```

Where */etc/passwd* is your file

The 2nd solution may be usefull if you have huge file:

```
my1stline=$(head -n1 /etc/passwd)
my2ndline=$(head -n2 /etc/passwd|grep -v "$my1stline")
cat /etc/passwd |grep -Ev "$my1stline|$my2ndline"
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach is similar to Gilles but I instead just reverse the file with cat and pipe that with the head command.

tac -r thefile.txt | head thisfile.txt
    (replaces files)

Answer (score 0):

Solution for BSD (macOS):

Remove first 2 lines:

```
tail -n $( echo "$(cat foo.txt | wc -l)-2" | bc )
```

Remove last 2 lines:

```
head -n $( echo "$(cat foo.txt | wc -l)-2" | bc )
```

...not very elegant but gets the job done!