# Can I use tail with a file both as input and destination?

Tags: logs, tail, stdout

I have a log file that gets big fast. I tried using `tail` with this syntax but it didn't work.

```
tail logfile.log -n 100000 > logfile.log
```

The output file is 0 bytes and blank. What am I doing wrong? Will I need to use an intermediary file?

Comment: See also [Is there a way to modify a file in-place?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11067)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this, but it's not really recommended:

```
{ rm logfile.log && tail -n 100000 > logfile.log ;} < logfile.log
```

This is better:

```
tail -n 100000 logfile.log > _tmp_ &&
  mv -- _tmp_ logfile.log
```

Comment: awesome. i should probably just use logrotate though. not sure what i was thinking.

Comment: Yes, you should definitely use logrotate.

Comment: the second method is better - but misses a very important step. If there is still a file handle open on logfile the footprint will exist on the disk until it is closed (and the application will continue to write to the old footprint - not the new file). You need to tell the application to reopen the file.

Comment: @symcbean, yes, very good point! I suppose that could be handled with _fuser_.