# Why can't I overwrite a file with processed value?

Tags: shell, io-redirection

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11067/is-there-a-way-to-modify-a-file-in-place) question prompted a thought I was not sure I understood well. I know that it is not possible or correct to use pipelines like `cat myfile | grep -v mypattern > myfile` due to how file handles are set up. However, why can't we simply use `cat myfile | grep -v mypattern| tee myfile>/dev/null` to modify the file in place? Are there any simple examples where it fails?

Specifically, does it lead to corruption or is it more of not being inplace edit, but rather overwrite?

Updating the question, I would appreciate if the answers would consider this too:

Is there problems with using `cat myfile | grep -v mypattern| bash -c 'rm myfile; cat > myfile'`?

Comment: Note that most of the usual text-processing tools that have an in-place edit option (e.g, `sed` or `perl`'s `-i` options) don't actually edit the files in-place. Instead, they write to a temporary file and `mv` it over the original when finished.  or something very similar to that.  Significantly, the temp file (and thus the original "in-place"-edited file) will have a new inode.  So `-i` etc are merely convenience features to save you the minor bother of doing it yourself.   BTW, if you really want to keep the same inode, you could script your edits with `ed`.

Comment: Reading from a file at the same time that you are overwriting it will __never__ be reliable.  Due to the vagaries of buffers and such, it may work occasionally.  But, it will never be something to depend on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: ONE DOES NOT SIMPLE OVERWRATE A FILE WITH THE PROCESSED VALUE]

The problem is that you cannot guarantee which is executed first. So you have to delay unlinking and writing to the file until you are absolutely sure that the file is opened for reading.

This will buffer the file in RAM before writing it.

```
cat foo | perl -e 'undef $/; @out=<>; open WRT,">",shift; print WRT @out' foo
```

Advantage: Keeps permissions of foo. If interrupted you have not lost the original foo.

Disadvantage: foo must fit in RAM.

This will open the file for reading, remove it, and `cat` from it. It in parallel wait for the file to disappear, and when it is gone `cat` to it.

```
(rm foo; cat) < foo | (perl -e 'while(-e "foo"){}'; cat >foo)
```

Advantage: Short. Works on files bigger than RAM.

Disadvantage: foo is gone as soon as you start.

```
(mv foo bar; cat) < foo | (perl -e 'while(-e "foo"){}'; cat >foo && rm bar)
```

Advantage: Works on files bigger than RAM. If fails, foo is kept as a backup in bar.

Comment: "The problem is that you cannot guarantee which is executed first." I understand that no shell guarantees it, but doesn't every shell set up the file handles first before running any command?

Comment: Also, `(rm foo; cat) < foo | (perl -e 'while(-e "foo"){}'; cat >foo)` can we be sure that the file handle for `cat >foo` will not be opened before `rm foo`?

Comment: Yes, because of the ;. The command is not spawned before perl finishes.

Comment: "but doesn't every shell set up the file handles first before running any command" This makes it worse: Before the reading cat starts reading, the writing cat will have truncated the file. Reading and writing the to the same actual file (not just the same file name) takes special care and is usually only done by database servers.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply do that because the `tee` command overwrites the file, making it shorter (probably) and eliminating the `cat` command's ability to read the data that was in the file.

If you could ensure that programs such as `tee` opened a *new* file, *and* if the shell guaranteed that `cat` opened its copy first, then you could copy from the old (actually deleted) file to the new.  But there's a lot of ifs and few guarantees.

You might suppose, for instance, that `cat` would start first, and `tee` later (when it is needed to capture data).  But the *shell* starts both, and unless `tee` is waiting for input before `cat` starts, the writes could fail (since no one is waiting, and those bytes have nowhere to go).  It is easier to make processes to wait on a `read` than on a `write`.

Comment: Ok, would `cat myfile | grep -v mypattern| bash -c 'rm myfile; cat > myfile' cause trouble?

Comment: In the case of `bash -c 'rm...'`, am I not assured of having a file handle to the file before deletion? because shell will set up the file handles before running the program?

Comment: @rahul No you are not. Mostly it will probably work, but if the initialization of `cat` is slow (e.g the command is not in cache and has to be read from disk), then you risk the bash command will start before the reading cat gets going. Think: (sleep 1; cat myfile) | grep -v mypattern| bash -c 'rm myfile; cat > myfile; which clearly fails