# Delete the first n bytes of files

Tags: text-processing, files, sed, awk

I've got an extreme problem, and all of the solutions I can imagine are complicated. According to my UNIX/Linux experience there **must** be an easy way.

I want to delete the first 31 bytes of each file in `/foo/`. Each file is long enough. Well, I'm sure somebody will deliver me a suprisingly easy solution I just can't imagine. Maybe awk?

Comment: Any awk/sed/ed solution will be line-oriented, so if you don't know the first line will be at least 31 characters then complications ensue.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
for file in /foo/*
do
  if [ -f "$file" ]
  then
    dd if="$file" of="$file.truncated" bs=31 skip=1 && mv "$file.truncated" "$file"
  fi
done
```

or the faster, thanks to Gilles' suggestion:

```
for file in /foo/*
    do
      if [ -f $file ]
      then
        tail +32c $file > $file.truncated && mv $file.truncated $file
      fi
    done
```

Note: Posix tail specify "-c +32" instead of "+32c" but Solaris default tail doesn't like it:

```
   $ /usr/bin/tail -c +32 /tmp/foo > /tmp/foo1
    tail: cannot open input
```

`/usr/xpg4/bin/tail` is fine with both syntaxes.

If you want to keep the original file permissions, replace

```
... && mv "$file.truncated" "$file"
```

by

```
... && cat "$file.truncated" "$file" && rm "$file.truncated"
```

Comment: Suggesting `dd` here is overkill, `tail` is more appropriate (simpler, less risk of a killer typo, no spurious messages on stderr).

Comment: You are right. I usually avoid commands intended to process text files when processing possibly binary ones but "tail +32c" will work here.

Comment: @jlliagre: You have written `cut`  (shouldn't that be tail? ... asis, it doesn't work for me...

Comment: Of course, it's tail. Sorry about the mismatch.

Comment: @jlliagre: On Solaris, you should have `/usr/xpg4/bin` ahead of `/usr/bin` on your `PATH`, or you'll be stuck in the early 1990s. Many unices (e.g. GNU, BusyBox) no longer support the historical `+32c` syntax, and take it to mean a file called `+32c` (as POSIX requires).

Comment: @Gilles: I should indeed as I usually strongly support standard conformance but in that specific case, I'm afraid I won't switch soon. What refrains me to do it is that change would trigger a gazillion of issues with existing scripts, and would distance me from the community of Solaris users who in their very large majority are still using the traditional commands.

Comment: tail: cannot open '+32c' for reading: No such file or directory

Comment: @AryehArmon As stated in my reply, you can use instead  "tail -c +32 $file" on POSIX systems.

Comment: @jlliagre this will give me last 32 bytes, correct?

Comment: @AryehArmon Incorrect, unless if the file size is exactly 64 bytes.

Comment: `mv` changes the file permissions. you can use `cat` instead of `mv` like this:
```tail +32c $file > $file.truncated && cat $file.truncated > $file && rm $file.truncated``` @jlliagre

Comment: @Hameda169 Thanks for your comment,suggestion added. Note that technically, it is not `mv` that changes permissions but the first redirection that sets potentially different ones to the intermediary one. `mv` keeps the source file permissions.

Answer (score 18):

The following commands cut first 31 bytes from `$file` (using `$file~` as a temp. copy):

```
dd if="$file" of="$file~" bs=1 skip=31
mv "$file~" "$file"
```

You only need to list or `find` all files under `/foo/` and execute the two above for every `$file` found.

Comment: Swapping bs and skip values will increase the performance.

Answer (score 16):

`tail -c +32` outputs its input minus the first 31 bytes. (Yes, the argument is off by one.) To edit a file in place, [use sponge](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5821/can-i-make-cut-change-a-file-in-place/5846#5846) in a loop, or if you don't have it and don't want to bother, do its job in the shell:

```
for x in /foo/*; do tail -c +32 "$x" | sponge "$x"; done
for x in /foo/*; do tail -c +32 "$x" >"$x.new" && mv "$x.new" "$x"; done
```

If the commands are interrupted for whatever reason (e.g. a power failure), it might be hard to figure out where you left off. Writing the new files to a separate directory would make things easier.

```
mkdir /foo.tmp
cd /foo
for x in *; do tail -c +42 -- "$x" >"/foo.tmp/$x" && rm -- "$x"; done
mv /foo.tmp/* /foo
rmdir /foo.tmp
```

If the files are really large (as in, large enough that having two copies of even a single one is a problem), you can use [one of the techniques mentioned in this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11067/is-there-a-way-to-modify-a-file-in-place).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
for each in /foo/*
do
  ex -sc '%!tail -c+32' -cx "$each"
done
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `!` run command
3. `x` save and close

Answer (score 2):

Using `dd` with block size 1 is extremely slow. It is possible to use a large block size while specifying the skip in bytes like this:

`dd iflag=skip_bytes if=infile.txt of=outfile.txt skip=31 bs=1M`

Comment: That is GNU dd only, BSD versions of dd do not have the `iflag` option.