# IO redirection and the head command

Tags: shell, io-redirection

I was trying to quickly edit an `.hgignore` file from the Cygwin bash shell today, and I added a line that was a mistake. I'm not sure if this was the best way to do it, but I quickly thought of using `head -1 .hgignore` to remove the offending line (I had previously only had one line in the file). Sure enough, when executed it gives the first line as the only output.

But when I tried to redirect the output and rewrite the file using `head -1 .hgignore > .hgignore`, the file was empty. Why does this happen? If I try appending instead, `head -1 .hgignore >> .hgignore`, it appends correctly but this is obviously not the desired result. Why does a truncating redirect not work in this case?

Comment: Similar: [Can I make `cut` change a file in place?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5821/can-i-make-cut-change-a-file-in-place), [How can I make iconv replace the input file with the converted output?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10241/how-can-i-make-iconv-replace-the-input-file-with-the-converted-output)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When the shell gets a command line like: `command > file.out` the shell itself opens (and maybe creates) the file named `file.out`.  The shell sets file descriptor 0 to the file file descriptor it got from the open.  That's how I/O redirection works: every process knows about file descriptors 0, 1 and 2.

The hard part about this is *how* to open `file.out`. Most of the time, you want `file.out` opened for write at offset 0 (i.e. truncated) and this is what the shell did for you. It truncated .hgignore, opened it for write, dup'ed the filedescriptor to 0, then exec'ed `head`.  Instant file clobbering.

In bash shell, you do a `set noclobber` to change this behavior.

Comment: Aha, I see. I did think that the shell was truncating the file before running the command, but I didn't know why. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 12):

I think Bruce answers [what's going on here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15826/io-redirection-and-the-head-command/1582915829) with the shell pipeline.

One of my favorite little utilities is the `sponge` command from [moreutils](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/moreutils/). It solves exactly this problem by "soaking" up all available input before it opens the target output file and writing the data. It allows you to write pipelines exactly how you expected to:

```
$ head -1 .hgignore | sponge .hgignore
```

The poor-man's solution is to pipe the output to a temporary file, then after the pipline is done (for example the next command you run) is to move the temp file back to the original file location.

```
$ head -1 .hgingore > .hgignore.tmp
$ mv .hgignore{.tmp,}
```

Comment: Looking at this a few years later, a thought occurred to me: couldn't we just do `head -1 .hgignore | tee .hgignore`? `tee` is in coreutils, and as a perk/side-effect, this also writes to STDOUT

Comment: @voithos To my knowledge `tee` opens and truncates the file it is writing to when it is instantiated just like everything else so it does not solve the main issue here of the race condition on reading the file contents before you truncate it with the write.

Comment: You bring up a point that I wasn't aware of, actually - namely, that piped commands are _started_ immediately, instead of sequentially. Is that accurate? I did, however, test it out and `tee` _seems_ to do the desired thing. I've got version `8.13` on my machine.

Comment: @voithos Yes commands in a pipline and all the input/output channels involved are started in reverse order so the pipeline is ready to receive data when the first one starts giving it. I suspect your test is flawed because you probably used too small a chunk of data and it got the whole thing cached in a read buffer before you needed it. The `tee` program will truncate your files, it is not setup to double buffer them.

Answer (score 3):

In

```
head -n 1 file > file
```

`file` is truncated before `head` is started, but if you write it:

```
head -n 1 file 1<> file
```

it's not as `file` is opened in read-write mode. However, when `head` finishes writing, it doesn't truncate the file, so the line above would be a no-op (`head` would just rewrite the first line over itself and leave the other ones untouched).

However, after `head` has returned and while the `fd` is still open, you can call another command that does the `truncate`.

For instance:

```
{ head -n 1 file; perl -e 'truncate STDOUT, tell STDOUT'; } 1<> file
```

What matters here is that `truncate` above, `head` just moves the cursor for fd 1 inside the file just after the first line. It does rewrite the first line which we didn't need it to, but that's not harmful.

With a POSIX head, we could actually get away  without rewriting that first line:

```
{ head -n 1 > /dev/null
  perl -e 'truncate STDIN, tell STDIN'
} <> file
```

Here, we're using the fact that `head` moves the cursor position in its stdin. While `head` would typically read its input by big chunks to improve performance, POSIX would require it (where possible) to `seek` back just after the first line if it had gone beyond it. Note however that not all implementations do it.

Alternatively, you can use the shell's `read` command instead in this case:

```
{ read -r dummy; perl -e 'truncate STDIN, tell STDIN'; } <> file
```

Comment: Stephane, do you know of a standard or coreutils command that can truncate `STDIN` similar to what you've accomplished using `perl` above

Comment: @1_CR, no. `dd` can truncate at any arbitrary _absolute_ offset in the file though. So you can determine the byte offset of the second line and truncate from there with `dd bs=1 seek="$offset" of=file`

Answer (score 1):

The Real Man's solution is

```
ed .hgignore
$d
wq
```

or as a one-liner

```
printf '%s\n' '$d' 'wq' | ed .hgignore
```

Or with GNU sed:

```
sed -i '$d' .hgignore
```

(No, I'm kidding. I'd use an interactive editor. `vi .hgignore` `GddZZ`)

Comment: I've wondered, is there any advantage to using `:wq` over `ZZ`?

Comment: Also, `:x` which is what my fingers do automatically

Comment: and `ZQ` is the same as `:q!`

Comment: ZZ and :x only write if there is something to write... :w always fsyncs the file to disk regardless if it needs it. I use :xa because I use tabs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '2,d|x' .hgignore
```

1. `2,` select lines 2 until end
2. `d` delete
3. `x` save and close

Answer (score 0):

For in-place file editing you may also use the open file handle trick as shown by Jürgen Hötzel in [Redirect output from sed 's/c/d/' myFile to myFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585438/redirect-output-from-sed-s-c-d-myfile-to-myfile).

```
exec 3<.hgignore
rm .hgignore  # prevent open file from being truncated
head -1 <&3 > .hgignore

ls -l .hgignore  # note that permissions may have changed
```

Comment: And just after `rm .hgignore` your power fails, taking away hours of hard work. Ok, it doesn't matter for `.hgignore`, but why would you do something that complicated anyway? Thus my downvote: technically correct but a very bad idea.

Comment: @Gilles, maybe not so good an idea, but that's for instance what `perl -i` (for inplace editing) does, and I wouldn't be surprised if some implementations of `sed -i` did it as well (though latest version of GNU `sed` seems not to).