# Why does `cat`ing a file into itself erase it?

Tags: cat, stdout, head

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IO redirection and the head command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15826/io-redirection-and-the-head-command)

I just wanted to remove all but the first line of a file. I did this:

```
head -1 foo.txt
```

... and verified that I saw only the first line. Then I did:

```
head -1 foo.txt > foo.txt
```

But instead of containing only the first line, `foo.txt` was now empty.

Turns out that `cat foo.txt > foo.txt` also empties the file.

Why?

Comment: A more interesting question (yet slightly more pedantic) would be to know if the evaluation order is defined in POSIX or is it implementation-specific.

Comment: @rahmu - True. I happen to be using zshell on OSX Lion.

Comment: @rahmu POSIX does specify the order but it doesn't need to because if you think about it for just a moment, you'll realize that the shell is the one that does the redirections and it has to do them *before* running the command, since it will be too late to do it after the command has already started.  Add that bit of common sense to the fact that the `>` operator includes truncation and this behavior becomes very logical.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Before the shell starts processing any data, it needs to make sure all the input and output is squared away.

So in your case using `> foo.txt` basically tells the system: "create a (new) file named `foo.txt` and stick all the output from this command into that file".

The problem is, as you found out, that that wipes out the previous contents.

Related, `>>` will *append* to an existing file.

**Update**:

Here's a solution using `sed`, handle with care:

```
 sed -i '2,$d' foo.txt
```

It will delete lines 2 to "last" *in-place* in file `foo.txt`. Best to try this out on a file you can afford to mess up first :)

This slightly modified version of the command will keep a copy of the original with the `.bak` extension:

```
 sed -i.bak '2,$d' foo.txt
```

You can specify any sequence of characters (or a single character) after the `-i` command line switch for the name of the "backup" (ie original) file.

Comment: Interesting. How would you remove all but the first line of a file, since `head -1 foo.txt > foo.txt` won't work?

Comment: @NathanLong Off the top of my head, I'd just use a different temporary file for the output and then rename it. Or is this something you are going to do over?

Comment: It's not something I'll do a lot. I just wondered if I was missing some obvious, better way.

Comment: This works: `head -1 foo.txt | tee foo.txt`

Comment: @NathanLong I just posted  a solution using `sed` that will fit your requirements too.

Comment: Regarding @Levon's temporary file. For 1 line of text a simple shell variable is enough: `IFS= read -r < foo.txt && echo "$REPLY" > foo.txt`. This is faster than the `sed` solution and more reliable than @NathanLong's `tee` workaround, which works only on small files. Regarding the `sed` solution, `sed -i 'q' foo.txt` is shorter and faster.

Comment: @manatwork thanks for the additional information, always good to add to the toolbox.

Comment: Please don't recommend `sed -i`.  It's not portable and probably doesn't even work correctly on links.  Non-portable alternatives include `cmd file | sponge file`.  Portable alternatives include `ed` (`ed` is a file editor; `sed` is a *stream* editor, not a file editor), which has more or less the same commands as `sed`, or a temporary file.

Comment: why does `tee` work here ? from [this SO discussion of tee vs. sponge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33638511/differences-between-sponge-and-tee) it seems like tee would have the same issues as just redirecting straight to the file.

Answer (score 3):

Because the shell that you use to invoke `cat` does the redirection indicated by `>`.

The shell (bash, zsh, ksh, dash, whatever) reads the command `cat foo.txt > foo.txt`. The shell has to set up the redirection indicated by `> foo.txt`.  `>` means to start writing the file from the top, `>>` would mean to append to foot.txt.

By the time the shell actually gets `cat` running, foo.txt has disappeared.