# Easy and elegant way to toggle values in /sys/

Tags: sysfs

What I really want is a NOT and write. I have files that are either `1` or `0`, like

```
/sys/class/leds/platform::mute/brightness
/sys/class/leds/platform::micmute/brightness
```

What I want is a way to turn the 1's to 0's and flush that result to the file. Something like `toggle` would otherwise do if the modules authors implemented it.

What's the most golfy-and-elegant way to do this **without calling a custom script**?

Answer (score 1):

A general purpose function may be:

```
toggle () { <"$1" tr 01 10 >"$1"; }
# or
toggle () { <"$1" tr 01 10 | tee "$1"; }
# or
toggle () { <"$1" tr 01 10 | sudo tee "$1"; }
# or
toggle () { <"$1" tr 01 10 | sudo tee "$1" >/dev/null; }
```

(depending on if you want to see the new value; and if you need to use `sudo`). You use it like this:

```
toggle /sys/class/leds/platform::mute/brightness
```

[Don't use it for files that can be truncated effectively](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41207/108618). In `/sys/` it works though.

---

This section is more detailed. It concentrates on `/sys/class/leds/*/brightness`. We can start with:

```
(cd /sys/class/leds/platform::mute && <brightness tr 01 10 >brightness)
```

Notes:

- This [wouldn't work with files that can be truncated effectively](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41207/108618).
- If you need `sudo` then `sudo sh -c 'cd /sys/… && <brightness tr 01 10 >brightness'` or [with `tee`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1417/108618), like above. A shell function may be handy:

  ```
  toggLED () { sudo sh -c 'cd "/sys/class/leds/$1" && <brightness tr 01 10 >brightness' sh "$1"; }
  toggLED platform::mute
  ```

  Or this quick and dirty version that supports wildcards (and code injection):

  ```
  toggLED () { sudo sh -c "cd /sys/class/leds/$1 && <brightness tr 01 10 >brightness"; }
  toggLED 'pla*:mute'
  toggLED 'foo; date'   # code injection possible
  ```
- In practice you can `chown` and/or `chmod` the `brightness` file(s) ([after each reboot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68897/108618)) and go without `sudo` to avoid having to type the password again and again:

  ```
  sudo chmod a+w /sys/class/leds/*/brightness
  toggLED () ( cd "/sys/class/leds/$1" && <brightness tr 01 10 >brightness )
  toggLED platform::mute
  ```

  An alternative is `NOPASSWD` in `sudoers`.
- I have `dell::kbd_backlight` where `max_brightness` is `2`. A general simple way to kinda cover it is with `tr 012 100` (which can be generalized further to `tr 0123 1000` etc.). A specific way to cycle fully is `tr 012 120`. A general way to cycle fully requires reading `max_brightness` and adjusting the transformation; not really golfy-and-elegant.