# How to search and replace multiple needles by one word via one expression?

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression, search

Assume you have a text file:

```
foo fnord bar
bizz foo poit
```

And now I would want to replace both "foo" and "bar" into "narf".

I know I could use:

```
 sed -e 's/foo/narf/g' -e 's/bar/narf/g' fileName
```

Yet I would like to work with an OR-operator that tells the regex to match both needles via one expression.

Hitting some manuals I suppose the pipe should fit my needs but I tried

```
sed -e 's/foo|bar/narf/g' -i fileName
```

and it didn't work and it's not even throwing an error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `-r` option for extended regexp syntax:

```
sed -r -e 's/foo|bar/narf/g'
```

Otherwise escape the disjunction as `\|`:

```
sed -e 's/foo\|bar/narf/g'
```

Answer (score 6):

There are many variations on [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) syntax. The very first tools in the unix world that had regular expressions did not have the full capabilities of regular expressions, only character sets (`[…]` and `.`), repetition (`*`) and line anchors (`^` and `$`). [Basic regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions) only have these operators. Sed is an old-school tool and uses basic regexps.

Many sed implementations have extensions for full regexp matching. Because the character `|` stands for itself, you need to use `\|` for alternation, and similarly `\(` and `\)` for grouping. Note that the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html) does not mandate that `\|` be supported in [basic regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_03), and some systems (e.g. [OpenBSD](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=re_format&sektion=7)) do not have it.

Some versions of sed have an option to switch to [extended regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Extended_Regular_Expressions), where `(…)` is used for grouping and `|` for alternation. With GNU sed (i.e. under Linux or Cygwin) or [Busybox](http://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#sed), pass the `-r` option. On [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed&sektion=1) or [OSX](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html), pass the `-E` option.

If your sed does not have alternation, you can call `awk` instead. It's mandated by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html), but a bit verbose for this task, and it does not support backreferences.

```
awk '{gsub(/foo|bar/, "narf")}' <fileName.old >fileName.new
```

By the way, only GNU and Busybox sed support file replacement in place. Awk and other versions of sed don't. See [Can I make `cut` change a file in place?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5821/can-i-make-cut-change-a-file-in-place)

If you have Perl, it's often handy in a one-tool-does-all kind of way for text processing one-liners. Most of what's easy in sed, awk and the rest isn't much more difficult in Perl, and you can get away with learning a single (if complex) tool.

```
perl -i -pe 's/foo|bar/narf/g' fileName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '%s/\vPA|QU/RO/g|x' file
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `s` substitute
3. `\v` turn on magic
4. `g` global replace
5. `x` save and close