# Does sort support sorting a file in-place, like `sed --in-place`?

Tags: text-processing, sort

Am I blind or is there no option like `--in-place` for `sort`?

In order to save results to the input file, sed uses `-i` (`--in-place`).

Redirecting the output of `sort` to the input file

```
sort < f > f
```

results in making it empty. If there is no `--in-place` option - maybe there is some trick how to do this in *handy* way?

(The only thing that cames to my mind:

```
sort < f > /tmp/f$$ ; cat /tmp/f$$ > f ; rm /tmp/f$$
```

Moving is not right choice, cause *file permissions* might be changed. That's why I overwrite with the contents of the temp file which I then remove.)

Comment: There is also [`insitu`](http://sigkill.dk/programs/insitu), allowing any commands to be used in-place.

Comment: @sr_, that's an interesting command, but it doesn't work with _any_ command, only ones that write no faster than they read (otherwise it'll clobber the input file before the command reads it).  There's no guarantee that it'll work with `sort`.

Comment: @cjm, I'm really not sure, but isn't [this](https://github.com/Athas/insitu/blob/master/insitu.c#L135) supposed to handle that case?

Comment: @sr_, I think you're right.  I read the description instead of looking at the source.  Although for really big files, it might run out of memory for the buffer and crash (it doesn't look like it checks for a NULL return from malloc).

Comment: @cjm: Oh yes, indeed.

Comment: http://sigkill.dk/projects/insitu/ is the updated link to sr_'s post.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

`sort` has the `-o` (or `--output`) option that takes a filename as argument. 
The program writes the data to a temporary file,
then overwrites the original input file after the sort is complete
(which can happen only after all the input data have been read). 
(This is essentially the same thing as what `sed -i` does.)

From `GNU sort` info page:

  `-o OUTPUT-FILE
  --output=OUTPUT-FILE`
    Write output to
    *OUTPUT-FILE*
    instead of standard output.  Normally,
    `sort`
    reads all input before opening
    *OUTPUT-FILE*
    , so you can
    safely sort a file in place by using commands like
    `sort -o F F`
    and
    `cat F | sort -o F`
    .  However,
    `sort`
    with
    `--merge`
    (
    `-m`
    )
    can open the output file before reading all input, so a command
    like
    `cat F | sort -m -o F - G`
    is not safe, as
    `sort`
    might start
    writing
    `F`
    before
    `cat`
    is done reading it.

On newer systems, `-o` cannot appear after an input file if
`POSIXLY_CORRECT` is set, e.g., `sort F -o F`.  Portable scripts
should specify `-o OUTPUT-FILE`
before any input files.
and from [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html):

  `-o  output`
    Specify the name of an output file to be used instead of the standard
    output. This file can be the same as one of the input files.

There have been reports that `sort` might discard (i.e., destroy)
some or all of your data
if you are out of disk space or out of disk quota,
or the system crashes while `sort` is writing the output file,
or some other error occurs.

In short, to sort a file in place, the following may be used:

```bsh
sort -o filename filename
```

Comment: I just used `sort -o file file` and realized I forgot `LC_ALL=C` (to speed `sort`) up, so hit ^C. OK, take tw--wait that finished quickly?? Apparently interrupting an in-place `sort` may make it truncate the file.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the [`sponge`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge) function, that first soaks the `stdin` and then writes it to a file, like:

```
sort < f | sponge f
```

The downside of `sponge` is that it will store the output temporary in memory, which can be problematic for large files. Otherwise you have to write it to a file first and then overwrite the original file.

As however is pointed out by other answers, in place modifications are in general not a good idea, since in the middle of a process (for instance the `sponge` one), the machine might crash and then you can lose both the original and new file. You better first write it to a different file and then use an atomic `mv` (move) instruction.

Comment: Another downside: sponge is not a standard Unix tool. It must be installed.

Comment: I've had bad experiences with `sponge`. If the source command fails (non-zero exit code), `sponge` still overwrites the file. This has never been what I wanted (though I concur the "correct" behavior is not a given).

Answer (score 8):

It's dangerous to overwrite the input file with the output file, because if the program or the system crashes while the file is being written, you've lost both.

A few programs (mostly GNU versions) have an in-place option (e.g. `-i` on perl and GNU sed; `-o` on GNU sort). They work by putting the data in a temporary file and then moving it into place.

For programs that have no such option, [Colin Watson's `sponge` utility](http://riva.ucam.org/%7Ecjwatson/blog/2006/02/06#2006-02-06-sponge) (included in [Joey Hess's moreutils](http://kitenet.net/%7Ejoey/code/moreutils/)) does the job atomically for any program (examples: [Can I make `cut` change a file in place?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5821/can-i-make-cut-change-a-file-in-place/5846#5846); [How can I make iconv replace the input file with the converted output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10241/how-can-i-make-iconv-replace-the-input-file-with-the-converted-output/10243#10243)). However, beware that `do_stuff | sponge myfile` always overwrites `myfile`, possibly with empty or incorrect output, even if `do_stuff` fails: `sponge` can't detect whether the command that's piped into it succeeded. So it's handy to type, but it's unsafe, compared to using a temporary file.

Only in those rare cases where you can't recreate the original file with the same permissions do I recommend overwriting the file in place. In this case, you'd better save the original input somewhere. And then you can simply process the copy of the input and send it into the original file.

```
cp -p f ~/f.backup
sort <~/f.backup >|f
rm ~/f.backup # optional
```

Comment: `sort -o` is not GNU specific, and is especially designed to orverride the file in place. `sort` cannot start writing its output before it has read its inputs fully (uses memory or temporary files to store data), so it comes quite naturally that it should be able to override its input.

Comment: And actually, it's one case where GNU `sort` is not POSIX as `sort -mo file1 file1 file2` is not guaranteed to work while traditional `sort`s know how to work around that (alread in Unix V7 in the 70s).

Comment: @JoelCross Odd, `sort -o` works for me with coreutils 8.25 and the property is documented in the manual (noting that it's only the case when sorting, not when merging). If you can reproduce this, send a bug report (indicating the exact command line, the exact input file(s), what system you're running it on and how you obtained the binary).

Comment: > It's dangerous to overwrite the input file with the output file, because if the program or the system crashes while the file is being written, you've lost both.

GNU `sort -o` will destroy both if it, or your system, crashes, or if your disk is full.

Comment: I've had bad experiences with `sponge`. If the source command fails (non-zero exit code), `sponge` still overwrites the file. This has never been what I wanted (though I concur that the "correct" behavior is not a given).

Answer (score 5):

Use `-o` or try the vim-way:

```
$ ex -s +'%!sort' -cxa file.txt
```