# Why did sort -u removed duplicates only in pipe?

Tags: sort, deduplication

In this command, `sort -u` removed duplicates.

```bsh
curl https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Special_page -s | grep -oP 'Special:\K[a-zA-Z0-9]*' | sort -u > special_page_names
```

In this command, it didn't.

```bsh
curl https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Special_page -s | grep -oP 'Special:\K[a-zA-Z0-9]*' > special_page_names
sort -u special_page_names
```

Why did sort -u removed duplicates only in pipe?
i.e., why didn't it remove duplicates when ran on a regular file?

Comment: In the second case, did `sort` print something else than you expected? What exactly? Or did you expect the tool to *modify* `special_page_names` maybe?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski sort didn't print anything I didn't expect, it's just that it didn't modify the file, although I did expect it to modify the file.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and put the clarification *in the question body*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort` is a filter. It reads input, modifies data somehow and prints output. `grep` is also a filter.

Usually a filter works by reading its standard input and writing to its standard output.

In case of `… | grep … | sort -u > special_page_names` the standard input of `sort` comes from `grep` and the standard output of `sort` goes to `special_page_names`. You requested this by using `|` between `grep` and `sort`, and by using `> special_page_names` at the end.

The syntax `sort -u special_page_names` tells the tool to ignore its standard input (in your interactive shell this is the terminal, standard input inherited from the shell) and read `special_page_names` instead. The standard output is not redirected; it's the standard output inherited from the shell, usually the terminal, *in your case the terminal*. The data flew from `special_page_names` *to your terminal*.

If you want to save the output of `sort -u special_page_names` to a regular file then one way is to redirect the output of `sort`, like in the first case. [Do not redirect back to `special_page_names` though](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/558773/108618); choose another file.

```
sort -u special_page_names > special_page_names_sorted
```

There are tools that can modify the file they read (e.g. text editors). There are filters with an option to overwrite the file they read (e.g. `sed -i`). You can make sort write to the same file by specifying the file both as an option-argument to `-o` and an operand:

```
sort -u -o special_page_names special_page_names
```