# Why do these two commands to write text-processing results back to the input file behave so differently?

Tags: text-processing, io-redirection, deduplication

I have a file `authorized_keys` and want to deduplicate the content, i.e. remove duplicate entries.

I found two possible solutions to achieve this:

1. Use `cat` and `uniq`, then redirect the output to the original file:

   ```bsh
   cat authorized_keys | uniq > authorized_keys
   ```
2. Use `sort` with the `-o` option:

   ```bsh
   sort -u ~/.ssh/authorized_keys -o ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
   ```

However, only the second option works. The first approach will result in an empty file.

If I redirect the output to a different file, as in

```bsh
cat authorized_keys | uniq > authorized_keys_2
```

the new file with has correct content, while

```bsh
cat authorized_keys | uniq > authorized_keys
```

leaves me with an empty `authorized_keys`.

Please help me understand the difference between these two methods.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators#186126

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bending a pipeline back into its origin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/558773/bending-a-pipeline-back-into-its-origin)

Comment: Btw, you should sort the file when using `uniq`, so the first way should actually be `sort authorized_keys | uniq`

Answer (score 1):

Your first solution won't work because you're reading and writing to a file at the same time. Doing so causes an empty file because a redirection, i.e. the '>' symbol is handled by your shell and instructs the shell to first open the file for writing, thus emptying it. Then your command, i.e.

```
cat authorized_keys | uniq
```

is executed, but since the file `authorized_keys` is now empty it results in an empty output. To avoid problems like this, you can use a temporary file, like you used `authorized_keys_2` to store the input then overwrite the original file with the temporary one

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon [SeetheMoar's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/696599/97255)...

From the [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

```
Redirecting Output

Redirection of output causes the file whose name results from the expansion
of word to be opened for writing on file descriptor n, or the standard 
output (file descriptor 1) if n is not specified. If the file does not exist 
it is created; if it does exist it is truncated to zero size.
```

Your file `authorized_keys` does exist, and so is truncated to zero, *before the command is executed*.

You *then* `cat` a zero length file, hence the resulting file is empty.

This process is explained in depth by [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186126/97255) to [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/97255)