# MD5 Hash modified trought netcat

Tags: linux, fedora, netcat, hashsum

I used dd to create a sample empty file with 1MB, edited the sample file, created a MD5 hash of the file, started a listener on the examiner machine, piped the output off to nc and compared the hashes. Why does the hash value is modified if i transmited the same data from the same file to it?

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/CaseStudies/sample.dd bs=1M count=1

hexedit sample.dd

ENTER

0x20000

68 65 72 65  20 49 20 61  6D 0A

Ctrl-X

dd if=/CaseStudies/sample.dd bs=4k | md5sum
```

output:

`fc3ef9193baf3a1d3fc67da5aa4510ae`

```
nc -lp 4444 > sample.dd

dd if=/CaseStudies/sample.dd bs=4k | nc -w3 127.0.0.1 4444

md5sum sample.dd
```

output:

`d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e sample.dd`

```
cmp sample.dd copy.dd
```

output:

`cmp: EOF on sample.dd which is empty`

For some reason the netcat isn't being able of sending the data through the connection. Could someone help me figuring out why?

Comment: Is your current working directory `/CaseStudies/`? See [*Bending a pipeline back into its origin*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/558773/108618). Does this answer your question?

Comment: *For some reason the netcat isn't being able of sending the data through the connection.  EOF on sample.dd which is empty* This is your issue, not checksums changing.